# Xcode - Team provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning, keychain, signing

i want to test app from xcode on real device. i have development certificate already added in Keychain Access - Certificates (this certificate was not created by me)

Xcode created Team Provisioning Profile , but i still got error:
**Xcode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain. 
Valid signing identity not found.**

I have also created private and public key.

But how to connect these keys with provisioning profile/development certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need both development certificate and private-key. You must to create development certificate yourself, or ask to export this pair the one who made it.

Comment: so i must contact person who created original development certificate and he must send me generated keys right ?

Comment: Yes. In the keyshain he can find his private key. if he will click on it,  there will be this sertificate. He should export this key and send to you. Then, just double-click on it, enter the password he seted to it,  and this should work.

Comment: thanks. what happens if i revoke original development certificate and create new one ?   there can be problems if there are some other developers using this certificate ?

Comment: No, untill thay will try to make new development profile. Yes, if thay will. But then, thay'll can revoke yours, and make new one.

Comment: ok, and when they revoke my profile, then i will have problems yes ? so best way is to send keys if i understand that

Comment: Yes. But  development profile "lives" 2 months. If you don't need to add new devices, you don't need to make new development profile/ so, you don't have problems for 2 months :)